# rxHistogram returns error: The element bIsPrediction does not exist in the list

Tags: revolution-r

I have Revolution R Enterprise 8.0 with RRO 3.2.2 installed and try to run a simple example - make a histogram from Titanic dataset:

```
library("RevoScaleR")
dataCsv <-  read.csv("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/course/Kaggle/train.csv")
dataXdf <- file.path("titanic.xdf")
rxImport(inData = dataCsv, outFile = dataXdf, overwrite = TRUE)
rxHistogram( ~ Age, data = dataXdf, xAxisMinMax = c(0, 520), numBreaks = 100, xNumTicks = 10)
```

and rxHistogram returns mystic error:

**Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  The element bIsPrediction does not exist in the list.**

Anybody knows how to fix it and what is actually the problem? Googling didn't give any results.

PS: hit the same error running rxDataStep

Comment: Hm... it's working for me with the same versions of RRE and RRO. Is that a fresh R session? What platform are you running on? Might be useful to post the results of `sessionInfo()` and `rxGetComputeContext()` - [here are mine for comparison](https://gist.github.com/mmparker-msft/d16dcbddca06c1adad90eaf05bb420b8).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Matt! 
I have checked event logs and found where it fails:
_Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-for-RRE\8.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\BxlServer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120.dll_
Based on that, I have choosen to uninstall R Server with prerequisites and install all over again, - and that helped.

Comment: got the same problem, but uninstall/re-install does not solve it. sessionInfo seems fine (post it on @mmparker-msft 's github). Any ideas what could I do?

Comment: @elikesprogramming, have you checked event log as well and it has the same error there?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by uninstalling Revolution R and installing it back again.